# findMaxReachable(GraphNode* start)

Tags: data-structures, graph

I have metod GraphNode* findMaxReachable(GraphNode* start),metod should return reference on node, from which one can reach most of rest of the nodes.

For example: function should return reference to A node, because form A there  is path to B,C,D nodes(reach three nodes). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQDXH.jpg)

A--> B -->C
     I
     D

Answer (score 0):

1. Iterate each un-visited vertices in any order. For each vertex `v`, run `DFS(v)` and traverse all adjacency nodes until there are no nodes can be visited.
2. Use `visited` flag to mark `true` which nodes are visited.
3. Use an hashmap to keep track the count of nodes can be reached from that certain node. In your example: `countMap['A'] = 3`, `countMap['B'] = 2` and `countMap['C'] = 1`.
4. During DFS, if encounter any node `x` already visited, return the `countMap['x']` and add.

Time and space complexity is linear `O(n)` where `n` is the number of nodes.

Let me know if you need any further explanation. I will provide pseudo-code if needed.

Comment: Thanks for answer.But I have one more question.                                     When i use DFS(v) i change status of node when node is visited(status=2).Do I need after DFS(v), to visit all nodes and restart value of status (status=0) ?

Comment: Ok i get it DFS(v) restart all values.